# After using Ubuntu installer for Windows, the monitor button enters a p

Tags: wubi, external-monitor, windows-vista, function-keys

I ran the Ubuntu installer for Windows (Wubi) and now my <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> button does not work in Windows anymore. This is the button that is usually the monitor switcher (primary, secondary, mirror). This now just types the letter p after a sub-second delay while I'm booted into Windows.

Is there any way to resolve this? (without removing Ubuntu).

Here are all my function buttons

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> (Windows Help): This does **not** work. <kbd>Flag</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> works but I don't care anyway.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> (Print): This still works, same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> (Internet): This still works.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> (Monitor): This is the one that I use most but just types the letter p after a very short delay
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> (Sleep): This still works.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> (Lock): This does **not** work. But I always use <kbd>Flag</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> anyway so I don't care.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> (Brighten Screen): This still works.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd> (Darken Screen): This still works.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> (Play/Pause): Have not tried.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> (Stop): Have not tried.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> (Next Track): Have not tried.
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> (Previous Track): Have not tried.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the letter P being typed is because Microsoft gave a recommendation to the hardware manufacturers to actually type "Win+P" if the person hits the monitor switching key.  This is hardcoded in your hardware.

http://mjg59.livejournal.com/121851.html

Comment: Win+P does not work either. It has the same effect of typing the letter p.

Comment: Which is why you're getting a P -- because Win+P is *meaningless* in Linux.  That Fn key, prior to this recommendation by Microsoft, would have sent an OS call.  Now it just sends a Windows-specific keyboard shortcut. If you were Greek, you might get Pi when you press that key though.

Comment: So are you saying that I am actually running Linux when I boot into Windows? All this is happening with Windows. Have not yet tried to boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: OH! You're asking on a Linux site, so I assumed you meant in Linux. I'm going to change your original question to specify.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is displaying a p is because the monitor switching function is still activated, if you're using Windows 7, just hit fn+F4 again and it will display the several display options, choose the one you need and hit Enter, this will deactivate the function and the F4 will become normal again.

Comment: Pressing Fn+F4 just types the letter 'p' according to the question.